# spacemacs|use-package-add-hook for :hook and :bind?

Tags: spacemacs, use-package

spacemacs provides `spacemacs|use-package-add-hook` for extending `:init` and `:config` but not `:hook` or other keywords.

Are there way to preserve the `use-package` syntax when writing spacemacs layers that uses preowned packages?